# Is there any software equivalant to link shell extension for ubuntu?

Tags: symbolic-link

I know a simple ln -s would work in this case. But sometimes it becomes too difficult if I had to link multiple files and folders to an specific location as symlinks. So it would be so helpful if there is software that can create a right click 'pick link source' or something link that and create 'drop link' as hardlink or symlink in anywhere I want it to be. I already checked by googling and nothing came up helpful. Regards

Comment: The shell _is_ software. You are not supposed to create symlinks left and right without a good reason; it should be a relatively rare activity, when you want to obtain a certain result. Doubly so for hard links.

Comment: But there has to be solution right ? ln -s might be helpful . But it comes to many files and folders there might be unexpected mistakes waiting for me to happen .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default file manager, Nautilus already has "Make Link" option in right click menu. Click it, and it will give you "Link to filename" link, which you then can place anywhere you want.

[image]

[image]